# Why does this iteration didn't return anything out?

Tags: python

```
def is_power(a,b):
    if a<b:
        is_power(b,a)
    elif a==b:
        return True
    else:
        if a%b !=0:
            return False
        else:
            is_power((a/b),b)


is_power(2,32)
```

I don't know why it didn't show anything out, but when I print the last line of the function "is_power((a/b),b)", it shows:

```
True
None
None
None
```

i write and run it in ipython notebook and python's version is 2.7.10.1

Comment: FunkySayu's answer not fully correct, see my correct answer and result below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have insert a return statement to the appropriate rows and have to add to the end of the code : `print is_power(x,y)`, 
which call the `is_power()` function and the return values to the output.
Note in IPython `is_power(x,y)` alone works too.

```
def is_power(a,b):
    if a<b:
        return is_power(b,a)
    elif a==b:
        return True
    else:
        if a%b !=0:
            return False
        else:
            return is_power((a/b),b)


print is_power(2,32)
```

**Output:**

```
True
```

Comment: Thanks you very much.

Comment: I was happy to help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
def is_power(a,b):
    if a<b:
        return is_power(b,a)
    elif a==b:
        return True
    else:
        if a%b !=0:
            return False
        else:
            return is_power((a/b),b)
```

You're running a recursive function without returning anything on steps.

```
is_power(2, 32)

First step  : if a < b: return is_power(32, 2) 
Second step : (else condition): return is_power(16, 2)
Thrid step  : (else condition): return is_power(8, 2)
Fourth step : (else condition): return is_power(4, 2)
Fifth step  : (else condition): return is_power(2, 2)
Sixth step  : (elif a==b):  return True

Result: True
```

If you miss any return statement, the code won't return anything else than `None`

Comment: This is not the correct answer

Comment: As you can see below the result of is_power(2,32) is True

Comment: Woups sorry it's a little mistake. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

You're program is made to return a `Boolean`, hence you will either get a `True` or a `False`.

If you want a different output, you'll have to code it to generate something else.

The only 2 return statements in your code are these :

```
elif a==b:
    return True
```

and :

```
else:
    if a%b !=0:
        return False
```

Therefore the only outputs you can expect are `True` and `False`.